# While converting from jquery to angularjs why am I getting this error?

Tags: ajax, json

Jquery Code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/ad_creation/get_campaign_objective/'+id,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response) {
            var campaign_objective = 'Error. Please refresh and try again.';
            if (response == 'WEBSITE_CONVERSIONS')
                campaign_objective = response;
            if (response == 'WEBSITE_CLICKS')
                campaign_objective = response;

            $('select[name=campaign_objective]').val(response).hide();
            $('#existing-campaign-objective').html(campaign_objective).show();
            $('#campaign-objective-select').show();

            if (campaign_objective == 'WEBSITE_CONVERSIONS'){
                // Show pixel block again.
                $('#select-pixel').show();
            }
            hideAjaxLoader('existing-campaign-loader');
        },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log('Invalid response', thrownError, xhr, ajaxOptions);
                hideAjaxLoader('existing-campaign-loader');
        }
    });
```

Angularjs code

```
  $http({
        method:'get',
        dataType:'text',
        url:'/ad_creation/get_campaign_objective/'+Number(id)
    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

I get the error Unexpected token w. I have also tried not casting the id to number but still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `content-type` of the response headers. 
If it is 'application/json' angular tries to parse the response. 
The error might be because of it.